# Simple Folder to folder batch python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am writing script to take shape files from a folder to Buffer it to given distance to Output folder with same name as input files. Here are block of codes.

```
# Name: Buffer_multiple file.py
# Usage : inFolder to outfolder Buffer analysis



# import system modules 
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings

arcpy.env.workspace= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

newFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


# get buffer size 
buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# get output feature class
outputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

for fc in newFC:
  arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, outputFeatureClass+fc, buffer)
```

It shows succeeded with No Output shapefile.

`Executing: Script C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Input 20 C:\Users\user1\Desktop\buffered
Start Time: Sun May 17 12:39:12 2015
Running script Script...
Completed script Script...
Succeeded at Sun May 17 12:39:14 2015 (Elapsed Time: 2.00 seconds)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output workspace and the FC name need to be properly concatenated.  You can do this by using [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```
# import system modules 
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings

arcpy.env.workspace= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  # type = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# get buffer size 
buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # type = integer

# get output feature class
outputWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # type = workspace

for fc in fcs:
    outfc = os.path.join(outputWorkspace, fc)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, outfc, buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks You Aaron..! it works but it is not added to display in Arcmap..

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not added to display"?

Comment: Output should automatically added to current Arcmap window after finish this geoprocessing .

Comment: You will need to use the arcpy.mapping module for that: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000032000000.  I would recommend opening a new question for that operation.

Comment: Okay thanks..! As far as I know all geoprocessing including python script, model builder should do that automatically. thank you once again..

Comment: You can specify adding the output to the display using ModelBuilder, but scripts should not add data to the display by default.